# On lubuntu 21.10 icons of .jpg files no longer represent the photo itself

Tags: lubuntu, icons

On Lubuntu 21.10 running on a Mac book pro (A1425), the desktop icons representing .jpg snapshot is showing a generic icon, white mountain on a green background and not a small sized representation of the snapshot itself, as in the previous version 21.04.
I did'n find any solution to this problem by myself.

Regards

Yves Collignon

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "*generic icon; white mount on a green background*" so a picture of it may have helped. LXQt aims to be *light* so doesn't include thumbnails by default; you need additional apps to enable that; you can see this reference on the Lubuntu forum/discourse - https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-to-enable-pdf-thumbnail-preview-on-pcmanfm-qt-on-lubuntu-20-04-lts/1195 or https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt/issues/1080 , https://github.com/lxqt/pcmanfm-qt/issues/1128 etc

Comment: There is maximal size for generating thumbnails, check your setting  in preferences of `pcmanfm-qt`

Comment: Thanks to Pasman pasmanski , i find a solution in pcmanfm-qt, my .jpeg files exceed the size limit fixed in the parameters, so i increase the limits and it works fine.

Comment: @pasmanpasmański  I'd appreciate an answer as you got it :) so thanks !

Comment: In pcmanfm-qt, in the preference menu, there is a submenu called "vignette" with a line "size limit of the .jpg file", if this limit is above the .jpg file size, the icons is changed as a vignette showing the photo itself.